Cannot build App to distribute in AppStore
I am working with Xcode 15 and I am trying to build the archive of my app to distribute it via the App Store. I choose Any iOS Device (arm64) and click the play button.

However, I am receiving this message:

A build only device cannot be used to run this target.
Please select an available device or choose a simulated device as the destination.

Which I do not understand.


You don't build an app for distribution by clicking the "play" button... Top menu bar ... Product -> Archive -- see: Apple's Docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/distribution

You can build your application to the AppStore using the Archive option.

First you have to select Any iOS Device (arm64)



Build your application for Archive from the product menu like:


